# Callback functions that depend on one another in Android Studio - a more elegant solution

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, callback, android-asynctask

I have 2 callback functions in my app, one of which requires the other one's result, so I want them to execute asynchronously. The scenario is this:

1. I obtain the device's token with `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()`. That's the 1st callback.
2. When I have the token, I use it in accessing the Firebase Realtime DB to get the user's data. That's the 2nd callback.

In my current solution, I'm using `AsyncTask` with a `Semaphore` in the `doInBackground` function, like so:

```
private class AsyncOp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                    token = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                    JSONObject requestObject = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        requestObject.put("token", token);
                        semaphore.release();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG_MAINACTIVITY, token);
                        semaphore.release();
                    }
                    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, REQUEST_URL + "token",
                            requestObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.i(TAG_MAINACTIVITY, "Token saved successfully");
                        }
                    },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Log.e(TAG_MAINACTIVITY, "Failed to save token - " + error);
                                }
                            });

                    _queue.add(req);
                }
            });

            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return token;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
            getUser(token);
        }
    }

 public void getUser(String token) {
        db.child("users").child(token).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    // Navigate to fragment where new users can sign up:
                    goToSignup();
                } else {
                    currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    assert currentUser != null;
                    updateHeadline(currentUser.getName()); // Update UI to display the user's name
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG_MAINACTIVITY, databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

and in my `OnCreate` I execute as follows:

```
_queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
AsyncOp getToken = new AsyncOp();
getToken.execute();
```

It works just fine, but I can't help but feel like I'm missing the whole point here and that there's a better solution that I can use. I've scoured other StackOverflow questions dealing with similar issues and found some suggestions, but I got tangled up trying to implement them, being pretty new to this whole ordeal (that's actually my first "real" project). I tried looking for something that would work like a `Promise` and found `Future` but I probably didn't do it properly since it didn't work. That's the only solution that worked for me, other than simply nesting `getUser(token)` inside the first callback. So if you have any ideas that would work for me, I'd be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase performs all network and disk I/O off the main thread. That means there is seldom a reason to run Firebase interactions in a background task.

Aside from that, the flow is significantly more complicated when you use a semaphore. I'd consider just putting the call to get a user into the completion handler of the previous call.

Combined that becomes:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
        token = instanceIdResult.getToken();
        JSONObject requestObject = new JSONObject();
        requestObject.put("token", token);

        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, REQUEST_URL + "token",
                requestObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i(TAG_MAINACTIVITY, "Token saved successfully");
                getUser(token);
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG_MAINACTIVITY, "Failed to save token - " + error);
            }
        });
        _queue.add(req);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Frank :) that's actually what I initially did, but I thought it would be better to avoid nesting the functions. Thanks.